# Why isn't my User Area PHP Code working?

Tags: php, mysql

My PHP code to Display "Please Login" to users that are not logged in doesn't display anything it will show the user their information when they are logged in but now when they aren't here is my code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!$_SESSION['logged']) 
    { 
      header("Location: http://www.westbournegames.co.uk/login/login.php");
      exit;

    echo "Please login";

    exit(); 

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because you have a header redirect and `exit();` The file never reaches the line:

`echo "Please login";`

Answer (score 0):

A user that is not logged in will enter the `if` branch. You should have used `!empty($_SESSION['logged']` to avoid a PHP notice which produces output.

Then the browser is redirected by the "header" call and the script exits.
It can never reach your "Please login" output.

To show this you must remove the `header()` and exit calls before echo.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing $_SESSION['logged'] to $_SESSION['views'] like this:
                $_SESSION['views']=1;

```
            <?php
            session_start();
            if ($_SESSION['views']!=1) { 
                header("Location: http://www.westbournegames.co.uk/login/login.php");
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer The code still appears to not show anything when not logged in and it shows the content that should be locked until the user is logged in   http://www.westbournegames.co.uk/user-area/

Comment: Unfortunately Its Still Tha Same.